# DataGridViewCellMouseClick ArgumentOutOfRange on double cick in individual cell

Tags: vb.net, events, datagridview

I have an event handler for my DataGridView on a double click. It is used to select rows in the table and use information from the selected row. This works perfectly, however, when I double click inside of a single selected cell, I get an ArgumentOutOfRange Exception on the following line:

Dim row As DataGridViewRow = dgvCustomers.SelectedRows(0)

I get why this exception happens. My question is how can I restrict my event to not trigger when double clicking inside a single cell to avoid this exception.

Comment: Is the DataGridView's SelectionMode property set to FullRowSelect?

Comment: FullRowSelect must be set. Any other mode causes an error.